# What are the benefits of placing a #define statement in a header (.h) file?

Tags: objective-c, scope, preprocessor

Is there any benefit to placing the `#define` preprocessor statement in the header file `(.h)` as opposed to the implementation file `(.m)`?

I have legacy code with `#define` statements sprinkled in both. Are these statements affected by scope?

Comment: What does `#define` have to do with your question? It's no different than anything else you put in a .h vs a .m.

Comment: Specifically, I want to know if there is any negative impact to grouping all of the #define statements together. Although they exist in both the .h and .m files, they are only being used in the .m file. 

My understanding is that preprocessors are unaware of your code's scope, so I don't see the benefit of having some in the .h file. I'm asking, in case there's some obvious benefit that I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, below we touch on where these `#define` statements go. But before I lost any sleep over where they go, I'd be worrying about whether they should be `#define` preprocessor statements at all. These preprocessor statements are not strongly typed and can introduce subtle issues. We don't use them as often as we once did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no benefits of having the `#define` in `.h` file other than, obviously, making them available in multiple `.m` files.

So, if it's something that potentially (even if you're not doing so yet) could be useful to multiple `.m` files, then put in in `.h` file. If it's something that could only be of value to a single `.m` file, then put that in the `.m` file.

A corollary of the above: Avoid repeating a `#define` in multiple `.m` files: If you have the same `#define` in multiple `.m` files, then that's a candidate of something that should be in a `.h` file.

In a comment you contemplate whether there is any "negative impact to grouping [them] together". If you're contemplating moving them to the `.h` file, I'd discourage that. Keep the scope as narrow as possible/logical. If you're contemplating moving them to the `.m` file, the question is whether any of these constants are potentially useful to a broader context.

Bottom line, I would not advise consolidating these to a single area just for the sake of keeping them together. Let the functional intent of the constant dictate where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely to make any noticeable difference but if the `#define` is only needed in one class then put it in the .m file if anything that imports the class needs to know about it put it in the .h file.

Say you have two classes `Foo` and `Bar`, `Bar.m` imports `Foo.h`. Any `#define`s in `Foo.h` will be read by the preprocessor while working on `Bar`. Any `#define`s that aren't used in `Bar` are pointless for the preprocessor to read. Any `#define`s in `Foo.m` will only be read when the preprocessor is working on `Foo` as nothing imports that file.